# On the Questions list, why do some questions have a grey background?

Tags: support, help-center

I often scroll through the newest questions https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions and find that one question has been highlighted in a darker grey panel. At time of writing, the question titled `LR Develop Module showing negative image!`, asked a few hours ago, is one such example.

I've wondered this for quite a long time, and I'm still unable to see any correlation with eg user type, number of answers, comments, views or anything? I also can't find anything in meta or help when searching for 'grey' or 'gray'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grey highlights questions that are tagged with any of your favorite tags.

That question is tagged with [lightroom], so unless I'm mistaken, you have [lightroom] as a favorite tag?

I imagine the style differs from site to site, which is why searching on "grey" would not turn anything up.

Comment: Lightroom was my only favourite tag, I hadn't been using favourite tags, best I start making use of them! thanks